# Dynatrace API - pull pure path information

Tags: rest, reporting, dynatrace

We are using Dynatrace in our organization for a long time. It is really a great tool for pointing out pain areas in case of performance and knowing what's happening in the system. However we found that reporting is not great. In our setup, data gets wiped-off in 20 days for non-PRD environment. It also looses all the details. To keep a track of underlying calls currently we need to take a screen shot of put the data manually in excel file. This helps us in comparing old results with latest development/ improvement.

We were wondering if there is any Dynatrace API available which can push the pure path information in JSON format. We checked [Dynatrace API](https://www.dynatrace.com/support/help/dynatrace-api/) page. But there is none. Creating excel files manually is waste of time. There is no value addition. Has anyone else found any work around for this?

e.g. for the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzMRe.png)  we want to have JSON having list of underlying DB calls shown under controller, their start-end time, time consumed details, etc..

Please help

Comment: As far as I see there is no such REST API available, you can discuss this in the Dynatrace Community forums at https://community.dynatrace.com/ to see if there is a way to achieve something like this.

Comment: The registration to this dynatrace community is paid.....

Comment: I don't think the community-pages are billed in addition to the product itself. As Dynatrace is a commercial product I expected that you have a contract and thus can access the community page.